# stack, pivot or something else?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to take a bunch of year columns and unpivot them to a single column.

Input is something like this:

```
Country 1990 1991
Canada    10   20
Scotland 100  200
```

and what I want is something like this:

```
Country Year  Value
Canada   1990    10
Canada   1991    20
Scotland 1990   100
Scotland 1991   200
```

Is there an easy way to do that?  I feel like I should be able to do this in one line with pandas but I can't get it.

The real transformation I want to do is even more complex.  The above is just one step along the way I think.

The full problem would be like what's below.  Can it be done in one step or would I have to do multiple transformations?

```
Country  Measure 1990 1991
Canada   M1        10   20
Canada   M2       0.1  0.2
Scotland M1       100  200
Scotland M2         1    2
```

I need this:

```
Country  Year  M1  M2
Canada   1990  10 0.1
Canada   1991  20 0.2
Scotland 1990 100   1
Scotland 1991 200   2
```

I've tried various combinations of `pivot` and `stack` and it's not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `melt` and `pivot_table`

```
df1 = (df.melt(['Country','Measure'], var_name='Year')
         .pivot_table(index=['Country', 'Year'], columns='Measure', values='value')
         .reset_index())

Out[321]:
Measure   Country  Year     M1   M2
0          Canada  1990   10.0  0.1
1          Canada  1991   20.0  0.2
2        Scotland  1990  100.0  1.0
3        Scotland  1991  200.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

On step:

```
df.set_index(['Country','Measure']).stack().unstack(1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
Measure   Country level_1     M1   M2
0          Canada    1990   10.0  0.1
1          Canada    1991   20.0  0.2
2        Scotland    1990  100.0  1.0
3        Scotland    1991  200.0  2.0
```

As to the first problem.

```
df.melt('Country')
```

Output:

```
    Country variable  value
0    Canada     1990     10
1  Scotland     1990    100
2    Canada     1991     20
3  Scotland     1991    200
```

Answer (score 0):

this is [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
new_df=df.melt(id_vars='Country',var_name='Year',value_name='M1').sort_values('M1')
new_df['M2']=new_df['M1']/100
print(new_df)
```

---

```
    Country  Year   M1   M2
0    Canada  1990   10  0.1
2    Canada  1991   20  0.2
1  Scotland  1990  100  1.0
3  Scotland  1991  200  2.0
```

---

**dataframe used**

```
print(df)

    Country  1990  1991
0    Canada    10    20
1  Scotland   100   200
```